# CDI Ambiguous resolution exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have three classes defined as below.

```
class A {
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends A{
}

class D{
//Inject class A
}
```

I am injecting class A in class D. CDI is throwing Ambiguous resolution exception. what is the right way to solve this ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Qualifiers, so your code would look like this:

```
@ClazzA
class A {
}

@ClazzB
class B extends A{
}

@ClassC
class C extends A{
}
```

and when you try to inject, you will do something like this:

```
@Inject @ClassA
A a;
```

Check the [Weld Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_qualifier_annotations)

Comment: Created qualifiers and annotated classes and Injection points with qualifier names. It is throwing UnsatisfiedResolutionException now.   org.apache.webbeans.exception.inject.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [classname] is not found with the qualifiers

Comment: Can you upload the project so i can check for you?

Comment: I had classpath issue in my project. It's working with qualifiers once I resolved the classpath issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The [`@Typed`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) annotation enables [restricting bean types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#restricting_bean_types) so that you can write:

```
class A {
}

@Typed(B.class)
class B extends A {
}

@Typed(C.class)
class C extends A {
}

class D {
//Inject class A
}
```

In your deployment, [beans types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_types) of the bean class `B` (resp. `C`) will be restricted to `B` and `Object` (resp. `C` and `Object`) so that there will only one bean whose bean types contain type `A` and the ambiguous resolution will be resolved.

Note that the `@Typed` annotation is available since CDI 1.0.

Comment: I will try with your suggestion as well. Other answer worked for me so accepting it as answer.

Comment: I prefer this answer because you dont need to create a new annotation for every subtype